# Which countries can punish you for doing drugs elsewhere?

Tags: international-travel, legal, drugs

I am a Russian citizen living in the Netherlands, my travel plans for this year include many EU countries, many trips to Russia as well as UK, US and Japan. At the moment, I have never done drugs, but I have been to coffeeshops with others. Recently, my bags have been drug tested in Warsaw airport. The test came out negative but that got me thinking:

- Many countries criminalize purchase of cannabis
- Many countries have the legal concept that a crime committed abroad is equivalent to a crime committed on their soil
- If I were a frequent visitor of Dutch coffeeshops I could easily have trace amounts of weed on my clothes and backpack which could be detected.

Are there notable precedents of travellers punished for doing drugs in a country where it's legal? If any of my stuff ever tests positive on a drug test in a country where it's illegal will telling the police that I have been to a coffeeshop in the Netherlands help me or hurt me? Should I establish a "quarantine rule" of not coming close to anything drug-related N days before I leave the Netherlands? How many days? Which countries should I be especially cautious about?

Comment: Many visa applications ask about drug-related convictions. I doubt the coffee shop excuse would carry much weight anywhere if your stuff tested positive eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/secondhand-weed-smoke-smell-on-luggage-when-traveling-to-japan-will-it-be-a-pro

Comment: Excuse for what? My hypothetical is not about actually carrying any drugs abroad - it's "can I run into trouble _just because_ the police suspects I did drugs in the Netherlands"

Comment: @Ox60 You asked if telling the authorities you’d previously visited a coffee shop would help if your stuff ever tested positive. If you test positive, they won’t care why or where. If you have no drug-related convictions, and never test positive on arrival in a country, the authorities of that country would have no reason to suspect you of using drugs.

Comment: It's nitpicking, but using drugs is often not even illegal, in many codes it's the possession.

Comment: @Traveller "If you test positive, they won’t care why or where." Really? Surely, a trafficker with his bag full of cocaine will be treated differently from someone who stayed over with a smoker friend, as in your example. Both can have their luggage test positive. So circumstances should matter, right?

Comment: @Ox60 As JakeDot says, it’s possession that counts. The punishment is likely to be harsher for a trafficker because of the magnitude of the crime but the basic immigration consequences would be the same.

Comment: @Traveller If I can't identify any drugs on my stuff, but a sophisticated chemical test can, does that count as posession?

Comment: @JakeDot that's actually important, if I can argue that I only got drugs at the coffeshops, it means I never posessed them...

Comment: The 'coffeeshop' excuse will not work as the are not legal, only tolerated. Possession if drugs remains illegal. And when you use drugs you possess it however short.

Comment: I think this is way too broad for the SE model, with too many cases and variables, and ultimately, too many opinions. I voted to close.

Comment: Is your question specifically about entry into a country or just in general. I don’t know about CBP. Police officers in the US can not arrest you for past drug use if you are not in possession of drugs when they search you, your vehicle, your domicile, or your possessions. However, they can arrest you for being under the influence of a controlled substance while performing certain activities such as driving a car or flying as a pilot. They can even arrest you for being in public while under the influence of controlled substances. CBP entry rules may be the same.

Comment: The look or smell of alcohol or drugs, or the appearance of the behavior of someone on alcohol or drugs is a viable reason to arouse the suspicion of law enforcement. This “probable cause” will justify their reason to conduct a search for controlled substances. A positive test of any substance will do the same. This holds true for many substances. For instance, gun powder residue from a recent trip to the rifle range or a hunting trip may trigger a more extensive search. Or, a car and house key holder that looks similar to a small pocket penknife. Just be polite and have nothing to hide.

Comment: Often laws within a country which criminalise acts outside that country only apply to nationals of that country, but this isn't universally true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction, although it only gives examples for a few western nations

Comment: Although I suppose if the nation considers "having enough drugs in/on you to test positive" to be a crime, extraterritorial jurisdiction doesn't really come into play

Comment: @Willeke But do they charge you for possession of drugs if you admit to using them in the past?  Can they even do that?  In Canada at least, I'm quite sure you cannot be arrested for possession by admitting to using drugs in the past.  They need to actually find it on your person.  It's not illegal to admit to prior drug use in a lot of places.

Comment: @Traveller You are suggesting that you have never met the sophisticated self animated high sensitivity drug detection units used at most international airports. Usually Beagles.

Comment: I vaguely remember a news story from the last year or so in which someone who used to run a coffee shop (or was it multiple?) in the Netherlands was jailed abroad (I think somewhere in South America), which is sort of related, though it was of a more serious "offense" than just drug use.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As an avid watcher of Border Security, I can tell you that when cocaine or other illegal drugs are detected by a swab (I never saw any swabbing for pot), this gives them a good reason to search the heck out of your bags, but if you aren't carrying, that's an end to it. I saw this at the US border, Canadian border, and Australian border. The Canadian border officers repeatedly said "we don't care what you do on your own time, just what you're bringing in, were you around people doing x?" but I did notice that saying "yes, I was" didn't stop the search or actually seem to be of any benefit to the traveler, except perhaps establishing them as honest and co-operative. At the land border, smelling pot on a person or their possessions definitely led to thorough searching of vehicles. So for a lot of countries, the "answers" in the comments above are generally true: as long as you're not carrying, they won't care that you used it before you arrived. (Side note: the lack of caring is not related to whether or not it's legal where you used it. Border officers are famous for not caring AT ALL about the laws elsewhere, only in their jurisdiction.)

However, this is not a general rule. [Singapore can](https://twitter.com/TravelGoC/status/1057707097549389824) ([and apparently does](https://globalnews.ca/news/4616086/singapore-cannabis-travel-drug-test/)) do drug tests on arrival and arrest people based on blood levels.

> “Any Singapore Citizen or Permanent Resident found to have abused controlled drugs overseas will be treated as if he/she had abused drugs in Singapore,” the statement read. “CNB conducts enforcement checks at Singapore’s checkpoints and will take action against those found to have consumed drugs overseas.” - Singapore Central Narcotics Bureau

(The government of Canada later added that they feel this applies to foreigners also.)

Also from that article, since you asked about a quarantine period:

> According to the Mayo Clinic, cannabis can be detected in urine three days after use for an occasional user (three times a week), 10 to 15 days for a daily user, or more than 30 days for a heavy chronic user (multiple times a day). For a blood test, it is typically detectable for one to two days, but can increase with more use, and saliva testing it is detectable for one to three days for occasional users. That number rises to 29 days for heavy users, according to Heathline.

Most of the articles I found about this included phrases like "the most serious anti drug policies in the world" or "famously strict drug policies" so don't assume Singapore is typical. There might not be any other countries doing it. But -- there might. Also, back in your own country, if there are drug tests related to employment, child custody, security clearances or whatnot, nobody is going to care "but it was legal where I was!" If it is illegal where they are testing, there will be consequences for testing positive even if you didn't break any laws.

Comment: Japanese citizens (not sure about Permanent Residents) also can be arrested for having consumed overseas, but not tourists. (Source: Watched drug-sniffing dog segments on Japanese TV shows.)

Comment: The trouble is, the detction threshold for cannibis is much longer than you say, and can be detcted 6 months out.  With hair testing, as long as your hair is.

Comment: I've heard that. I would appreciate references. The quote in my answer is from a news article that asked a qualified source. This is non theoretical for me - cannabis is legal here, and I have family who want to visit Singapore and worry about blood levels. They have mentioned 6 months also. But nobody has a source or reference. If you have one, @Harper-ReinstateMonica, please share it.

Comment: I knew some Korean students in college. They all told me that they are drug tested upon their return to Korea and that they would get in legal trouble if they smoked cannabis in the US, even if it was legal (state law) when they did it.

Comment: *The government of Canada later added that they feel this applies to foreigners also.*  Did you mean to say Singapore after that quote about Singapore's CNB?

Comment: No, the tweet from the Canadian government is what is saying that foreigners might also be tested.

Comment: 14. Taking drugs before you enter the country : Penalties for drug possession in Singapore range from fines as high as $20,000 to 10 years in prison. In certain cases, if the amount of the drug is high enough, the punishment can even be a death penalty. **Singapore officials have the right to conduct anonymous drug tests without a warrant**, so any drugs taken before you enter the country can still put you at risk. – *16 odd things that are illegal in Singapore*, https://www.businessinsider.com/things-that-are-illegal-in-singapore-2015-7

Comment: The general rule for Singapore is, [*don't screw around*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_P._Fay).

Comment: "The government of Canada later added that they feel this applies to foreigners also." What does this mean?

Comment: I think the tweet I linked to (https://twitter.com/TravelGoC/status/1057707097549389824) is pretty clear. Foreigners can be tested on arrival and face consequences.

Answer (score 28):

Some jurisdictions can take a very stern view to ANY suggestion of recent past drug use.

A few years ago a British citizen was arrested on arrival in Dubai for having 0.003g of cannabis embedded in the dirt on the bottom of his shoe.  He was jailed for 4 years, before being pardoned after a few months.  Source: [BBC news](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/7234786.stm).

The same story mentions several other cases, including a Swiss citizen, also jailed for 4 years, for having 3 poppy seeds from a bread roll on his clothing.

Comment: technically, those stories refer to people importing drugs into those countries, not to past use. Still draconian to be sure.

Comment: @KateGregory True, but jailing someone for importing 3 poppy seeds from a bread roll, possibly because of the association of poppies with heroin, is a pretty extreme conclusion in my opinion.

Comment: absolutely! And it fits with the idea of being punished for accidental behavior. But the question asked about past drug use, not about having something in a fold of cloth or on your shoe that led to accidental importing. Were the people in that story tested for previous use at all?

Comment: The poppy seed example is especially heinous: poppy seeds aren't a drug and don't contain any drugs. The problem is that many tests for opiates don't actually test for opiates; instead, they test for certain proteins which are present in the entire plant.

Comment: That particular poppy seed case seems to be rumour, I have never seen a primary source for it. However, I'd still stay away from the UAE with poppy seeds: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43648/did-dubai-sentence-someone-to-four-years-in-jail-for-possession-of-three-poppy-s/43649#43649

Comment: @Martha maybe so, but in the case of the UAE, the Dubai customs site explicitly mentions poppy seeds as prohibited: https://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/eServices/ServicesForTravellers/CustomsDuties/Pages/PermittedItems.aspx

Comment: @KateGregory the question also asks about belongings testing positive for trace amounts due to being around it, which this answer definitely applies to.

Comment: This didn’t happen at the border, but a sailor in San Diego was busted for having a marijuana seed under the back seat of a rented car in 1982.  (No citation, but I worked at the same base at the time.)

Comment: @Martha poppy seeds do contain certain amount of opiates. If you eat enough, it can make you fail a drug test even though you never got high.

Comment: @VladimirF: no, that's precisely what I'm saying. Poppy seeds do *not* contain any opiates, but they do show up on drug tests, because *those tests do* ***not*** *actually test for the presence of opiates*. It's like, I dunno, looking for bread, but actually testing for yeast, and thus giving false positives for beer.

Comment: @Martha No, I say again, they DO CONTAIN opiates, morphine and codeine specifically https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3297423 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1856638 Various countries have their limits on the allowable content in them but they do contain some.

Comment: @Martha Poppy seeds (from bagels) can be used to grow poppy plants which do produce narcotics. Even after the bagel is cooked, some seeds are viable. And they can then be used to produce seeds to grow more plants. Source: I've seen some elderly members of a gardening club actually do this to grow that specific variety of poppy (it is quite large and beautiful), and the birds that eat parts of those plants do in fact fly away in interesting and unique patterns. I don't recommend trying this at home unless you're an extremely harmless-looking elderly person who loves gardening.

Comment: @user3067860 Why? It is perfectly legal here (for flowers and food). Well, one must report to authorities if above 1 a.

Comment: @nick cooked seeds (as they were in bread), non-viable for cultivation.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm never sure about the legality, which is why I don't recommend it. I will admit that the old ladies in the gardening group grow it quite openly and never seem to have any trouble, but they also are particularly harmless looking.

Comment: @Mindwin Like I said, I know a gardening group that has dis-proven this--by growing poppies from bagels that were cooked. Probably the success rate is low, but it's non-zero.

Comment: @Martha Poppy seeds, particularly fresh, unwashed seeds, do contain trace amounts of opiate alkaloids. Addicts who can't get a fix are known to buy them in bulk and boil them into a tea to fight off the sickness.

Comment: @Martha For some reasons, people upvote your reaction to me, but it is wrong. I say again, poppy seeds **DO CONTAIN** opiates.

Answer (score 20):

In South Korea you can go to jail if you smoked Marijuana in a country where it is legal (like Canada or the Netherlands). Some K-pop stars were send to jail for smoking weed in the Netherlands.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_South_Korea#Recreational_use)

[NY Times post](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/23/world/asia/cannabis-canada-south-korea.html)

[Fortune post](https://fortune.com/2018/10/23/canada-marijuana-south-korea/)

[The Guardian post](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/oct/23/bong-arm-of-the-law-south-korea-says-it-will-arrest-citizens-who-smoke-weed-in-canada)

Comment: But that applies to South Koreans only. If a, say, Polish traveller smoked weed in Netherlands and then went to Sout Korea, it would be fine.

Comment: @Crowley yes that is true, only South Koreans are subject to Korean laws outside of S. Korea.

Comment: @Jungkook But everybody is subject to South Korean laws in South Korea, no?

Comment: @lambshaanxy that is correct

Comment: @lambshaanxy American soldiers aren't, when on official duty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangju_highway_incident. But the point is that if you're not a South Korean, you can't be prosecuted for acts which take place outside of South Korea (with some limited exceptions unrelated to drug use)

Answer (score 5):

You mention EU countries. Belgium doesn't care about drug use in other countries. However, it's illegal to drive a car in Belgium if there's any trace of previous drug use in your blood, and obviously the country of drug use doesn't matter. Random roadside tests are uncommon, but they happen, so it's not advisable to drive a car in Belgium for weeks (or months, depending on the source) after using drugs.

Comment: Saliva tests are being used more and more in Belgium and they can detect "hard drugs" like cocaine, speed, meth until a few days afterwards and "soft drugs" like weed or hasj until a bit over a week (for regular users it can be longer)